# Review link not working

Tags: bug, review-queues, error-message

I just tried accessing the [review link](https://stackoverflow.com/review) a few times but it constantly gave a 500 error response after around 20-30 seconds.

The error kept occurring until I **logged out**, **then logged in**. Now the review link is working, but I guess I'm not the only one happening this, because the review page has a bit more pending review than usual.

May it be a cookies issue?
Did it happen to anyone else?

Comment: Review on SO or MSO?

Comment: Oh sorry, SO only

Comment: **It is working now.** Maybe because many questions were being added to queues at that time (May be).

Comment: Seemed more like an internal timeout, due to the response time. Yeah maybe some struggling with an internal redis/sql request..

Comment: My guess is still some cookies issue with a recent update, because It cleared after I logged in again.